# Spring test throwing org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test

My web application working fine. But when I am trying to add test case for my dao class . I am getting error mentioned ion last of this post

I have both UserDaoTest and UserDaoImpl/UserDao in same folder

Here is UserDaoTest

```
    package com.User.orm.dao;

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

    @TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
            DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
    public class UserDaoTest {

        @Autowired
        private UserDao UserDao;

        @Test
        public void testFind() throws Exception {
            List<UserProfile> up = UserDao.searchUsers("test",null);
            System.out.println("test");

        }

    }
```

Here is UserDaoImpl

```
    package com.User.orm.dao;


    @Component
    public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<User>  implements UserDao{


        public UserResponseDTO searchUsers(String user, Filter filter){}

    }
```

But getting below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.User.orm.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make configuration class for unit tests. Define configuration class by implementing "@Configuration" annotation. then use @ComponentScan to get bean from the package.

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.User.orm.dao")
 public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDao userDao() {
        return new UserDao();
    }

  }
```

Make sure that UserDao has @Component or @Service annotation.

Comment: Also, as a suggestion, I recommend using `@Repository` for your DAOs instead of `@Component`. It helps to specify the intent of the class as well qualifies the unchecked exceptions, thrown by DAOs, to be translated into DataAccessException.

Comment: yes you are right , we can use Repository instead of @Component, It will become more specific and will perform good for error handling, but most of the times Component works just fine.

Comment: One more thing...If you're going to go with @Rezwan's approach, I'm pretty sure you'll need to annotate your test class with `@WebAppConfiguration` as well. Hope this works :)